# Angular 7 + Angular Material => Form Validation Error not appearing until leaves focus

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-form-validation

```
<form (ngSubmit)="saveChanges()">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" >
      <mat-label>New ID</mat-label>
      <input required matInput name="newName" [style]="elemStyles" [formControl]="email">
      <mat-error *ngIf="email.invalid && (email.dirty || email.touched)">
        <p class="error-message" *ngIf="email.errors.duplicateId">ID <strong>already</strong> exists.</p>
        <p class="error-message" *ngIf="email.errors.required">This field is <strong>required.</strong></p>
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <div class="action-buttons">
      <button type="submit" [disabled]="email.invalid" mat-mini-fab class="accept action-button">
        <mat-icon fontSet="fontawesome" fontIcon="fa-check" class="fa-xs action"></mat-icon>
      </button>
      <button type="submit" mat-mini-fab class="cancel action-button">
        <mat-icon fontSet="fontawesome" fontIcon="fa-times" class="fa-xs action"></mat-icon>
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

The mat-error part is only showing **AFTER** leaving the focus of the input field. The Accept Button gets disabled tho. Any info how to fix this behaviour to get the error message while the user types?

I tried removing `(email.dirty || email.touched)` too, but it's not working :/

My Custom Validator:

```
export class DuplicateIDValidator {
  static duplicateIDValidator(pageStructure: PageStructureService) {
    return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
      return pageStructure.pages.every(page => page.questionId !== control.value.toLowerCase()
        || page.questionId === pageStructure.selectedPages[0].questionId) ? null : {duplicateId: true};
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The solution was an ErrorStateMatcher.

Answer (score 5):

Be aware that `<mat-error>` does not get displayed until the control's `touched` flag is true. This means that on the first focus of a field, and then changes to it, any `<mat-error>` will not show until the field is blurred (and the `touched` flag is set to `true`).

To force `<mat-error>` to show even when the field is first focussed (and has an invalid value), mark the control as touched:

```
this.control.markAsTouched();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `email.invalid && (email.dirty || email.touched)` with `email.invalid` if you want the error to be displayed immediately rather than when the control is touched (when leaving the focus)

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing the second condition on your `*ngIf`, i.e to remove `(email.dirty || email.touched)`

This is how your code should look like:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="email.invalid">
  <p class="error-message" *ngIf="email.errors.duplicateId">ID <strong>already</strong> exists.</p>
  <p class="error-message" *ngIf="email.errors.required">This field is <strong>required.</strong></p>
</mat-error>
```

This will cause the mat-error directive to be rendered once there are any errors.

Comment: the (email.dirty || email.touched) was added afterwards, I tried it before like you said and it's also not working

Comment: What is the name of your `FormGroup`? Also, are your form validator methods working?

Comment: I think so because my Accept button gets disabled but the error message mat-error is not disabled. It's basically the same *ngIf. I'm only using a FormControl with the required Validator and a Custom Validator I added in the question.

Comment: When you initialised your `FormControl` on your component.ts, did you pass those validators?  Something like `new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, DuplicateIDValidator.duplicateIDValidator])`. Also, you can try adding a `console.log()` statement in your custom validator to print your FormControl values? This is to check if the validator is being triggered correctly?

Comment: Yes, I added the validator and  the correct values are printed in the custom validator